# Nested HTML table - width=x% no longer working correctly

Tags: html

I have a table that has worked correctly for many years, but recently the table widths have gone slightly haywire. It's an old HTML site I maintain but didn't write (it should be rewritten in CSS) but the owner doesn't want to do it yet and it's a very large site.

No changes were made to the table structure, yet the width=x % is no longer working correctly on part of it. I know the table is messy and overly complex

I've stared at this and I know I'm missing something easy. There are some errors in the table, but they have not prevented any rendering engine from displaying it properly until recently (client noticed it a few days ago).

The exact problem is that a nested table (see ****problem*** below) is not allocating space on a 25%, x%, 25% basis. The x% is slightly under 50%, but the two outer columns should be 25% each (when the browser is large enough) and they used to scale equally. Now, the left column is always larger than the right proportionally, the middle expands and shrinks with the size of the browser, but the right column is always too small and crowded.

I'm sorry for the code. It's a messy table and I wanted to cut what I thought was extraneous but leave the structure.

I'm stumped. Any help would be appreciated.

CLARIFICATION. This table has 3 nested tables within it. Those 3 tables used to resize as you changed the size of the browser window, but now only 2 of the 3 are scaling. The left-most and the center tables scale and re-size as part of the whole; the right-most nested table no longer scales and has shrunk below the 25% width threshold as specified. This is a new phenomenon, but none of the base code has been changed (I verified from a 1 year old copy of the page).

```
<table width="100%" height="500" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="5" height="54" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><br /> </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td colspan="5" height="21" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><some images><br />    </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td colspan="5" height="25" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><br />  </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td colspan="3" width="100%" height="1" align="left" valign="middle" </td>
      </tr>
      <tr> ************PROBLEM STARTS HERE ***************
        <td colspan="1"   width="25%" height="485" valign="middle" align="right" >
            <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                  <td align="right" valign="middle">
                        <p class="x">
                          <a href="#"></a><br />
                          <a href="#"></a><br />
                        </p>
                   </td>
                  <td width="15" align="right" valign="middle"></td>
                </tr>
          </table></td>

        <td colspan="1" height="450" width="1" valign="top" align="right" </td>
        <td colspan="1" height="485" align="center" valign="top">
            <table width="100%" border="0" valign="top" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="1" height="485" align="center" valign="middle"></td>
                </tr>
          </table></td>
        <td colspan="1" height="450" width="1" valign="top" align="right" </td>
        <td colspan="1" height="485" width="25%" valign="middle" align="right" bgcolor="#84968A"><table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td width="15" align="right" valign="top"></td>
                <td align="left" valign="middle">
                    <p class="x">
                         <a href="#"></a><br />
                         <a href="#"></a><br />
                    </p>
                 </td>
         </tr>
        </table></td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You have un-closed `tds`, for example, right befor «problem starts here». Try closing them and check the result. Also, that td sould be colspan=5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, problem lies in the row above where you have "problem starts here":

```
<td colspan="3" width="100%" height="1" align="left" valign="middle"> </td>
```

You are saying that 3 columns are 100% of the width.  Then, your next row has 5 cells.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually that doesn't affect it. You can redefine the number of columns. I tried changing it to 5 for fun, but it made no difference. The leftmost, and center columns are expanding the the right most is stuck. The other interesting thing is that the table has been working for years. I just broke, probably due to rendering engine changes in the new browsers.

Comment: Thank you. You're right.. I don't know what was happening when I modified that before, but for some reason it didn't update or didn't clear from my cache. That one change, after trying everything else, made the difference so thank you. The worst part about it is that I tried it so long ago I could have saved a lot of time... LOL                  I also don't understand why it has been working that way. I checked an old copy from Aug 2008 and it says colspan=3.. I'm stumped why it broke now, but I guess all the browsers have been undated (tried it in IE 8/9, FF 3.6, Chrome, Safari, etc.